# jQuery: Dynamically appending <option> with disabled and selected attributes

Tags: jquery, append

I have successfully appended an `<option>` element to my `<select>` along with its `value`, `text` and `placeholder`. However, I had trouble finding out what the correct keyword is for assigning `disabled` and `selected`. The process of appending in my `<select>` is done when an event occurs which in turn triggers AJAX to send some data that I'll use to set the attributes of my `<option>`.

This here is my append code, **I merely want to add the** `disabled` **and** `selected` **attributes to my** `<option>`:

```js
$('#selectID').append( $('<option>', {
  value : 'Some value I got from my AJAX',
  text  : 'Another value I got from my AJAX'
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently, the keyword is the attribute's value itself. Do the following:

```js
$('#selectID').append(
  $('<option>', {
    value     : 'Some value I got from my AJAX',
    text      : 'Another value I got from my AJAX',
    //This here
    disabled  : 'disabled',
    selected  : 'selected'
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectID"></select>
```